# Reload/Retry Script Or Url-redirection

Tags: html, redirect

When the internet is not available a local html which uses meta redirect, shows the default message:

"Web page not available, Can not load http://example.com/stats/ check your internet connection"

So what I am looking for, is a solution to show "Retry/Reload" button on the page or url-redirection to another local page rather than this message.

Comment: @Cole When internet is not available, or page is unable to connect to the website, then the pop up or retry button have to be used than normal &quot;Webpage not available&quot; message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (navigator.onLine) {window.location = "http://example.com/stats/"; } else { alert('offline'); }

Answer (score 0):

To reload current webpage:

```html
<button onclick="window.location.reload();">Reload</button>
```

To redirect to new page:

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';">Redirect</button>
```